# Connection with multiple database with spring boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, database-connection, spring-jdbc

Showing error while connecting to database using spring boot:

classMethod FAILED
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

```
    Caused by:
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/tomtom/workflow/iris/uitest/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

        Caused by:
        javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

            Caused by:
            org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution

                Caused by:
                org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.

                    Caused by:
                    java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
```

**Properties:**

```
# PostgreSQL DB - "iris"
spring.datasource.jdbc-url= jdbc:postgresql://172.xx.xx.93:5442/workflow?currentSchema=workflow
spring.datasource.type=com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.username=workflow
spring.datasource.password=workflow

# PostgreSQL DB - "accesspoint"
secondary.datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://172.xx.xxx.44:5442/workflow?currentSchema=accesspoint
secondary.datasource.username=dba_admin
secondary.datasource.password=dba_admin

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL82Dialect
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto= update
```

Classes For bean.For secondary datasource:

```
package com.tomtom.workflow.acesspoint;       

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "accessPointEntityManagerFactory",
  transactionManagerRef = "accessPointTransactionManager",
  basePackages = { "com.tomtom.workflow.acesspoint" }
)
public class AccessPointDbConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean(name = "accessPointDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "accesspoint.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "accessPointEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean accessPointEntityManagerFactory() {
        /*
         * return builder .dataSource(dataSource)
         * .packages("com.tomtom.workflow.acesspoint") .persistenceUnit("baseline_info")
         * .build();
         */

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.tomtom.workflow.acesspoint" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Bean(name = "accessPointTransactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager accessPointTransactionManager(
            @Qualifier("accessPointEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory accessPointEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(accessPointEntityManagerFactory);
    }
    }
```

For Primary datasource i have written this class.

```
package com.tomtom.workflow.iris.uitest;   

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory", basePackages = {
        "com.tomtom.workflow.iris.uitest" })
@Profile(Profiles.DATABASE)
class DatabaseConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.tomtom.workflow.iris.uitest.db.model" });

        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

        return em;
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

I have connected both the database by pg admin and they are active.
Please help.

Comment: For multiple databases you'll have to create multiple versions of datasource related beans yourself. https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

Comment: I have create two classes for that:

Comment: `java.net.SocketTimeoutException` means that your program is not able to connect to database instance, verify the connection to database.